# Spring PlatformTransactionManager

Tags: spring, spring-transactions

In my code PlatformTransactionManager is not working, I am using below code in my normal pojo java class

## Java Class

```
TransactionDefinition def = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
TransactionStatus status = transactionManager.getTransaction(def);
```

here i am getting def value `PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT`
after that in `TransactionStatus`  i am getting `NullPointerException`

```
Error 

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.polaris.collateral.services.CollateralInterfaceBean.attachCollateralLine(JavaClass.java:138)
    at com.polaris.collateral.collateral.domain.CollMaintDomain.earMarkColl(Dao.java:2993)
```

And also i configured datasource in my xml file

```
<bean id="JavaClass" class="com.test.JavaClass">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Pleas take some time to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a question and provide additional information.

Comment: may you post spring configuration? how did you configure the transaction manager and transaction support?

Answer (score 0):

You also need the PlatformTransactionManager bean in your xml.config that is @Autowired in your transactional class. 
It also looks like you went for the programmatic approach, so I guess it would go something like this.

```
public foo(){
    DefaultTransactionDefinition def = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
    def.setName("Transaction");
    def.setPropagationBehavior(TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRED); 
    TransactionStatus ts = txMgr.getTransaction(def);
     try
    {
        txMgr.getTransaction(def);

        //some business logic 
        txMgr.commit(ts);

        logger.info("Commit Transaction");
        return bar;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        txMgr.rollback(ts);
        logger.info("Rollback Transaction");
        throw ex;
    }
}
```